# Naming constant class attribute in Python

Tags: python, constants, conventions

I have a class attribute, which is **constant in a class** but has a **different value** in **its subclasses or sibling classes**. And the attribute is used in a method in the base class.

In this case, should I express the attribute `address` as constant, that is, with SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE like `ADDRESS`?

For example,

```
class BaseClass:
    address = ''

    @classmethod
    def print_address(cls):
        print(cls.address)

class SubClass1(BaseClass):
    address = 'sub1'

class SubClass2(BaseClass):
    address = 'sub2'
```

Or, is there a better way to do the same thing?

Comment: I am not sure this kind of question is on-topic in stackoverflow. If it is not proper, please let me know

Comment: If it has different values in subclasses then `cls.address` doesn't have a constant value at compile-time so it is not, by definition, a constant. `lower_snake_case` is appropriate IMO; but I don't know how to give a non-opinion-based answer to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Constants are usually defined on a module level and written in all capital letters with underscores separating words. Examples include MAX_OVERFLOW and TOTAL.
>
> - https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#constants

So, if it's a class attribute, it's not considered as a constant in terms of PEP-8.

However, there are few real-world exceptions.

### Constants for Django models

In examples from Django documentation, constants for `choices` of fields are encapsulated into the model itself:

```py
class Student(models.Model):
    FRESHMAN = 'FR'
    SOPHOMORE = 'SO'
    JUNIOR = 'JR'
    SENIOR = 'SR'
    GRADUATE = 'GR'
    YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES = [
        (FRESHMAN, 'Freshman'),
        (SOPHOMORE, 'Sophomore'),
        (JUNIOR, 'Junior'),
        (SENIOR, 'Senior'),
        (GRADUATE, 'Graduate'),
    ]
    year_in_school = models.CharField(
        max_length=2,
        choices=YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES,
        default=FRESHMAN,
    )
```

Source: [Model field reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#choices)

### Enums

`enum.Enum` uses SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE for enum values. For example:

```py
from enum import Enum

class Color(Enum):
    RED = 1
    GREEN = 2
    BLUE = 3
```

Source: [enum.Enum documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#creating-an-enum)